# System of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We suppose that we have a system of differential equations $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \tag 1$$ 
where there order of $L_1 y$ is $n$ and the order of $L_2 y$ is $m$ and the coefficients of the highest-order term is $1$.

Let $n<m$.

Let $d_jL_i$ be the $j$th derivative of $L_i y$.

We define the differential equation $d_{m-n}L_1 y-L_2 y=0$ the order of which is smaller than the order of $L_2 y$.

So the system $(1)$ is equivalent to the system $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
d_{m-n}L_1 y-L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So the initial system is equivalent to a system of smaller order.

We do the same procedure until we get a system of the form $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L y=0\\ 
\alpha 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ where the order of $L y$ is $0$ and $\alpha$ doesn't contain $x$, i.e., it is a relation between the parameters.

So we conclude to one differential equation.

That means that any system can be replaced by one differential equation.

Is this correct?

$$$$

---

**Example:**

We have the system :

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=y'+y=0\\ 
L_2 y=y''+y'+y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The order of $L_2 y$, which is $2$, is greater than the order of $L_1 y$, which is $1$.

So it is equivalent to the system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
L_2' y=d_1L_1 y-L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=y'+y=0\\ 
L_2' y=y''+y'-y''-y'-y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=y'+y=0\\ 
L_2' y=-y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So multiply at the second equation by $-1$ so that the coefficient of the highest order term is $1$.

So we get $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=y'+y=0\\ 
L_2' y=y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The order of $L_1 y$, which is $1$, is greater than the order of $L_2' y$, which is $0$.

So it is equivalent to the system

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
d_1L_2' y-L_1 y=0\\ 
L_2' y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1' y=y'-y'-y=0\\ 
L_2' y=y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1' y=-y=0\\ 
L_2' y=y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow y=0$$

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: you also want $Lu=0$ not $L=0$

Comment: I changed $L=0$ to $Ly=0$. I also added an example... @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: do the same change in example:)....reading now

Comment: I did it... @MichaelMedvinsky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking another example 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=ay'+by=0\\ 
L_2y=cy''+dy'+ey=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
now this becomre
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=ay'+by=0\\ 
L_2'y=ay''+by' + cy''+dy'+ey=(a+ c)y''+(b +d)y'+ey=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
Note that in this case $L'$ is doesn't really "better" then $L$.

When you talking about linear system of differential equations you should think about vector $y=(x,x',x'',x''',\dots,x^{(n)})^T$ and some matrix of coefficients $A$ and some vector function $b(x)=(b_1(x),\dots,b_n(x))$, such that 
$$y'=Ay+b$$

**Very simple examples**

1)  $y''+y'+y=0$, denote $v=y'$, $w=y$ then $v'+v+w=0$ 
become $$\pmatrix{y'\\y''}=\frac{d}{dt}\pmatrix{w\\v}=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&-1}\pmatrix{w\\v}=\pmatrix{v\\-v-w}
$$

2) The other way(different example)

$$\begin{cases}{x'=x+y\\ y'=x-y}\end{cases}
\rightarrow
\begin{cases}{x''=x'+y'\\ y'=x-y}\end{cases}
\rightarrow
x''=x'+x-y$$

This is very simmilar to what you want, but how one can solve it in this form?

The system can be solved of course.
Rewrite as
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
Since
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1-\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
 -\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 1-\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
one multiply the system by $$\begin{pmatrix}
 1-\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
to get

$$\begin{pmatrix}\tilde x\\\tilde y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) x+y\\ 
\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) x+y\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}\tilde x\\\tilde y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 -\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\tilde x\\\tilde y\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Isn't it as follows? $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=ay'+by=0\\ 
L_2y=cy''+dy'+ey=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 

We want that the coefficients of the highest order term is $1$, so we divide the differential equations by $a$ and $c$ respectively. 

So we get 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\ 
L_2y=y''+\frac{d}{c}y'+\frac{e}{c}y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
L_2' y=d_{1}L_1 y-L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2' y=y''+\frac{b}{a}y'-(y''+\frac{d}{c}y'+\frac{e}{c}y)=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2 ' y = \left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )y'-\frac{e}{c}y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: $$\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2 ' y = y'-\frac{e}{c\left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )}y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Comment: $$ \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2'' y=d_{0}L_1 y-L_2' y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2'' y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y-\left (y'-\frac{e}{c\left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )}y\right )=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2'' y=\left (\frac{b}{a}+\frac{e}{c\left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )} \right ) y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Comment: $$\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1y=y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0\\\ 
L_2'' y= y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1' y=d_{1}L_2 y-L_1 y=0 \\ 
L_2'' y= y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1' y=y'-\left (y'+\frac{b}{a}y\right )=0 \\ 
L_2'' y= y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1' y=-\frac{b}{a}y=0 \\ 
L_2'' y= y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Rightarrow y=0$$

Comment: so you got a trivial solution ($y=0$) after all this long process? 
more logical would be to consider $\left (\frac{b}{a}+\frac{e}{c\left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )} \right )=0$ doesn't it?

Comment: Do you mean to have the following $$y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0 \ \land \ \left (\frac{b}{a}+\frac{e}{c\left (\frac{b}{a}-\frac{d}{c}\right )} \right )=0$$ ?

Comment: not necessary, but could be if  for example $e =-\frac{b (b c-a d)}{a^2}$

Comment: Then we would have the differential equation $y'+\frac{b}{a}y=0$, or not?

Comment: yes, but you lost information about second equation

Comment: But the methodology is correct, isn't it? If yes, do we have to prove it? Or is the description of the procedure enough?

Comment: you had a system of two equations, reduced it to one equation without preserving the information about the original system, i.e. in this case you omitted the second equation. How do you think to find the solution for the system now?

Comment: I don't want to solve the system, I just want to have one differential equation, since I have shown which conditions  a differential equation has to satisfy so that it has a solution. Then we check if the equation that the system has been reduced to satisfies these conditions. $$$$ Could you maybe take a look at my new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556507/can-we-express-this-condition-using-only-these-operations ?

Comment: yes, but if you "reduce" it to something not equivalent to one you started from it make no sense...

Comment: But why is it not equivalent? Except from the one differential equation, at the last step we have also an other equation, a relation between the parameters. Isn't it $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix} 
L_1 y=0\\ 
d_{m-n}L_1 y-L_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ since when $L_1=0$ then $d_{m-n}L_1 y-L_2 y=0  \Rightarrow L_2 y=0$.

Comment: you implied at some place here above a trivial solution only after all these changes while at the beginning you had also non trivial solution...

Comment: Let $L$ be the language $\{+, \frac{d}{dx} , 0, 1\}$ and $R$ the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. $$$$ 
In my notes I found the following proposition:

Comment: Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be non-zero differential operators and $f_1$ and $f_2$ terms of $L$. 
Then there id a differential operator $L$, with order less or equal to the maximum of the set $\{\text{ord}(D_1), \text{ord}(D_2)\}$, and a term $f$ of $L$, such that in the ring $R$, the following formulas are equivalent: 
$$D_1(y)=f_1 \ \land \ D_2(y)=f_2 \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ D(y)=f$$ 
Furthermore, there is an algorithm for the construction of $D$ and $f$ from $D_1$, $D_2$, $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: So, isn't this algorithm the one I described in my initial post?

Comment: I have problem with a "less or equal" in your proposition. But your algorithm satisfy it.

Comment: Why is there a problem with "less or equal" ?

Comment: because it contradict with equivalency.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: nth order differential equation can be transformed to a system of $n$ first order equations and vice verse. So if for example you have two first order equations you should get second order equation - the order is increased.

Comment: But, when the order of $L_2$ is greater than that of $L_1$ then with the transformation $d_{m-n}L_1 y-L_2 y=0$, the highest order term cancels out, so the order is less than that of $L_2$. Isn't this right?

Comment: consider third order equation, you can transfrom it into 3 first order equation or into 2 equation with one of first and another of second order. when you combine them back you should get the original 3rd order equation back. your proposition claim that the order should be at most two.

Comment: Using the transformation $$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
D_1 y=0\\ 
d_{m-n}D_1 y-D_2 y=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$ we end up with one equation when for example $d_{m-n}D_1=D_2$, right? 

$$$$ Suppose we have the third order equation $$D_1 y=y'''+y''+8y'+7y=0$$ We calculate from example $D_2=d_1 D_1=y''''+y'''+8y''+7y'=0$. So we have the following $$D y=y'''+y''+8y'+7y=0 \\ \Leftrightarrow \\ D_1 y=y'''+y''+8y'+7y=0 \land D_2=y''''+y'''+8y''+7y'=0$$ Is this correct?

Comment: This is very special case. Your homogeneous system is redundant. The solution to $D_2$ is an integral of the solution to $D_1$, but the only common solution is the solution to $D_1$. However, 
in the in homogeneous case it may be inconsistent.
For example $y'=0\land y''=0$ has a solution constant and a line, the only line that is also constant is a constant. However $y'=\sin t\land y''=t$ has a solution$ y= c_1-\cos (t)\land y= \frac{t^3}{6} + c_3 t+c_2$ have no common solution.

Comment: At the sentence the equivalent formulas should be $$D_1(y)=f_1 \ \land \ D_2(y)=f_2 \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ D(y)=f \land \phi$$ where $\phi$ is a formula that doesn't contain any $y$. $$$$ Applying the above algorithm at your example $$y'=\sin t\land y''=t$$ I get $y'=\sin t\land \cos t=t$, so $$y=c_1-\cos t \land \cos t=t$$.

Comment: $t-\cos t$ has only one root, does one point looks like a solution to differential equation?

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the two solutions $y= c_1-\cos (t)\land y= \frac{t^3}{6} + c_3 t+c_2$ have one intersection point?

Comment: I fail see here the solution that satisfies the second equation, if you see it, I'm done here.

Comment: I have to think about it... $$$$ Could you take also a look at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569318/non-zero-solutions-of-the-system ?