# Can we express this condition using only these operations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have the differential equation $y'=y$.

It's solution is $y=ce^x$.

So that we get the solution $y=e^x$, we need the condition $y(0)=1$.

Can we express this condition using only the operations $\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx}\}$ ?

For example if we have the differential equation $xy'=ky$, its solution is $y=Cx^k$. To get the solution $y=x^k$, we need the condition $y(1)=1$, which can be expresses as $x-1 \mid y-1$ which is equivalent to $\exists F: (x-1)F=y-1$.

Can we do something similar in this case

Comment: I am not sure about your definition of "is divisible by" for functions, but  what is wrong with using $x\mid y-1$?

Comment: Because we are looking at a language where the divisibility is not defined. Only the operations  $+$, $\cdot$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ are defined. @robjohn

Comment: So write it as $\exists F:xF=y-1$

Comment: Do you mean at the case $y=e^x$ ? @robjohn Why does it stand that $$y(0)=1 \Leftrightarrow \exists F: xF=y-1$$ ? $$$$ For example when we have $y=Cx^k$ we prove it as follows:

Comment: Let $y$ be a solution of the differential equation $xy'=ky$ then $y(1)=1 \Leftrightarrow \exists F \ (x-1)F=y-1$. 

Proof. 
Since $y$ is a solution of $xy'=ky$ we have that $y=C x^k$. 
If $y(1)=1$ then $C=1$, i.e., $y=x^k$, then $$y-1=x^k-1=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+\dots +1) \Rightarrow x-1 \mid y-1.$$ So $\exists F \ (x-1)F=y-1$. 

@robjohn

Comment: For the other direction, we suppose that $\exists F \ (x-1)F=y-1$, i.e., $x-1 \mid y-1$. Then $$x-1 \mid C x^k-1 \Rightarrow x-1 \mid C x^k-C+C -1 \Rightarrow x-1 \mid C (x^k-1)+C-1 \\  \Rightarrow x-1 \mid C (x-1)(x^{k-1}+\dots +1)+C -1.$$ So it must stand that $C-1=0 \Rightarrow C=1$. So $y(1)=1$.  @robjohn

Comment: Your polynomial argument only works when $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\ge1$. The equation has the same solution even when $k\not\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: At the polynomial argument I supposed that $k \in \mathbb{N}$, since other wise $x^k$ is not a polynomial, right? @robjohn $$$$ Can we do something similar for the exponential case?

Comment: Suppose $y(0)=1$, then define $$F=\left\{\begin{array}{}\frac{y-1}x&\text{if }x\ne0\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{array}\right.$$ If we have an $F$ so that $xF=y-1$, then $x=0$ immediately implies $y=1$.

Comment: I understand!! Do we have to prove it as I proved above the polynomial case? @robjohn

Comment: To prove this we say the following: $$$$ Since $y$ is a solution of the differential equation $y'=y$ we have that $y=ce^x$. If $y(0)=1$ then $c=1$, i.e., $y=e^x$. How can we continue to get $x \mid y-1$ ? @robjohn

Comment: I got stuck right now... Suppose that we are looking in the ring $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$, so $y \in \mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. Is then the divisibility $x \mid y-1$ defined? @robjohn

Comment: I am unsure of the ring. Is $\lambda$ supposed to be fixed? Are we looking at things like $3e^{ix}+3e^{-ix}+e^{-\pi x}$?

Comment: The elements of the ring are of the form $$\sum_{i=0}^N \alpha_i e^{\lambda_i x}$$ where $\alpha_i , \lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$. @robjohn

Comment: Since $x$ is not in this ring, you could try something like $e^x-1\mid y-1$ That forces $y(0)=1$.

Comment: Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$. 

I want to define the relation $e^x-1 \mid e^{kx}-1$ (where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) in the language $\{+, \cdot , \frac{d}{dx} , 0, 1\}$, so we can use only these operations, the addition, the multiplication and the derivation, and all the terms come from these operations and from $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Since in the language we don't have the symbol $e^x$, I thought that this is the solution of the differential equation $y_1'=y_1$ when we apply the condition $y_1(0)=1$. 

And we get $e^{kx}$ from the differential equation $y_2'=ky_2 , \ y_2(0)=1$. 

So we have $$e^x-1 \mid e^{kx}-1 \Leftrightarrow \exists y_1 , y_2 \in R : y_1'=y_1  \land  y_1(0)=1  \land  y_2'=ky_2  \land  y_2(0)=1 \land y_1-1 \mid y_2 -1$$

Comment: The relation $y_1-1 \mid y_2 -1$ can be defined in the language as follows: $$\exists h \in R : (y_1-1 )h=y_2 -1$$ right? 


But how can we define in the language the relations $$y_1(0)=1 \text{ and } y_2(0)=1$$ ? Or isn't it possible to express this in that language? Is it necessary to add the symbol $e^x$ in the language? @robjohn

Comment: What do you mean "necessary to add"? Isn't $e^x$ already in your ring?

Comment: Does it maybe stand that $$k \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow ce^x -1 \mid ce^{kx}-1$$ ? @robjohn

Comment: No. Not unless $c=c^k$.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... If we suppose that $c=c^k$, how can we prove the implication $$k \in \mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow ce^x -1 \mid c^k e^{kx}-1$$ ? @robjohn

Comment: Well, it's not true for negative $k$. Other than than, use the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: So, does it stand that $$k \in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow ce^x -1 \mid c^k e^{kx}-1$$ ? @robjohn Ok, I wll try it...

Comment: If $k\in \mathbb{N}: c^k e^{kx}-1=(ce^x)^k-1=(ce^x-1)((ce^x)^{k-1}+\dots +1) \Rightarrow ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$ 

If $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$ what can we say to conclude that $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ? @robjohn How can we use the sum of a geometric series ?

Comment: It is $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i =\frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1}$$ right? @robjohn

Comment: So do we say that since $$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i =\frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1}$$ it follows that $$k \in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow ce^x -1 \mid c^k e^{kx}-1$$ ? @robjohn

Comment: That only shows $\Rightarrow$ for $k\ge1$. To show $\Leftarrow$, you need to suppose that there is some $F=\sum\limits_jc_je^{jx}$ so that $\left(ce^x-1\right)F=\left(c^ke^{kx}-1\right)$ and show that $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But how can we show then that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? @robjohn

Comment: For the direction $\Rightarrow$ is it as follows? $$$$ 
$- k >0 :$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i=\frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1} \\ \Rightarrow (ce^x)^k-1=(ce^x-1)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (ce^x)^i$$ 
So when $k$ is an integer $>0$ we have that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$.

Comment: $ - k <0 : $ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} ((ce^x)^{-1})^i=\frac{\left (\frac{1}{ce^x}\right )^k-1}{\frac{1}{ce^x}-1}=\frac{\frac{1-(ce^x)^k}{(ce^x)^k}}{\frac{1-ce^x}{ce^x}}=\frac{ce^x}{(ce^x)^k} \frac{1-(ce^x)^k}{1-ce^x} =\frac{1}{(ce^x)^{k-1}} \frac{(ce^x)^k-1}{ce^x-1} \\ \Rightarrow (ce^x)^k-1=(ce^x-1)(ce^x)^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} ((ce^x)^{-1})^i$$ 
So when $k$ is an integer $<0$ we have that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$. 


$$$$ 

Is this correct?

Comment: For the other direction: 

We suppose that $ce^x-1 \mid c^ke^{kx}-1$, that means the solutions of $ce^x-1$ are also solutions of $c^ke^{kx}-1$, right? 

Does this help? @robjohn