# Non-zero solutions of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computability, stability-in-odes

I have concluded to the following results:

1. An homogeneous linear differential equation in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ has a solution if at least one root of the characteristic equation is equal to $0$.
2. An homogeneous linear differential equation in the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ has always a solution.

So, is there an algorithm that, given an equation $Dy=0$ and inequations $D_i y\neq 0$, determines whether the system $\displaystyle{Dy=0 \wedge D_i y\ne 0}$ has non-zero solutions in the above rings?

How can we can check whether the system $\displaystyle{Dy=0 \wedge D_i y\ne 0}$ has non-zero solutions in each ring or not?

$D$ and $D_i$, $i=1, \dots , n$ are differential operators.

Comment: By differential equation in the ring, do you mean an equation of the form $\partial u = f$ with $f\in R$ (and accepted solutions are also in $R$), where $\partial$ is the obvious differential in your case?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The differential operator is linear and the coefficients are constants. @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: Do you have an idea how can we can check whether the system $\displaystyle{Dy=0 \wedge D_i y\ne 0}$ has non-zero solutions in each ring or not? @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: I have to say that I don't really understand what do you mean by $D_i$...

Comment: $D$ and $D_i$, $i=1, \dots , n$ are differential operators. @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, $Dy=0$ is a subring, let's call it $R_0$, so maybe you can try to characterize it and simply look at the other equations in $R_0$?

Comment: What do you mean to characterize it? @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Comment: Do you mean to find which properties should be satisfied so that $Dy=0$ ? @DanielRobert-Nicoud

Answer (score 1):

Let $D = P(d/dx)$ and $D_i = P_i(d/dx)$ where $P$ and $P_i$ are polynomials (the characteristic polynomials of the differential operators).

In order for $D u = 0$ to have a nontrivial solution of the form $g(x) \exp(\lambda x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial, we need $\lambda$ to be a root of $P$.  If it is a root of multiplicity $m$, then the solutions of this form are
$g(x) \exp(\lambda x)$ where $g$ is any polynomial of degree at most $m$.

Thus the general solution of $D u = 0$ is $\sum_j g_j(x) \exp(\lambda_j x)$ where the sum is over all roots $\lambda_j$ of $P$, and each $g_j$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m_j$, where $m_j$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$ as a root of $P$.

In order for such a solution (with all allowed coefficients nonzero) to also be a solution of $D_i u = 0$, what is needed is  that each $\lambda_j$ is also a root of $P_i$, with multiplicity at least $m_j$.  Of course, if that happens, $P$ must divide $P_i$.  Thus the condition for there to be a solution of $Du = 0$  that is not a solution of any $D_i u = 0$ is that $P$ does not divide any of the $P_i$.

In order for there to be a solution of $Du = 0$ in $\mathbb C[x]$ that is not a solution of $D_i u = 0$, what is needed is that the multiplicity of $0$ as a root of $P$ is greater than its multiplicity as a root of $P_i$.
Thus the condition for there to be a solution of $Du = 0$  in $\mathbb C[x]$ that is not a solution of any $D_i u = 0$ is that the multiplicity 
of $0$ as a root of $P$ is greater than the maximum of its multiplicities as a root of the $P_i$.

Comment: At the second paragraph, you say that we need $\lambda$ to be a root of $P$. Why do we need that condition?

Comment: If it isn't, there is no nontrivial solution of the form $g(x) \exp(\lambda x)$.